# Discord bot responding to user with their username

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot has code that lets you say hello to it. Currently, it looks like this

```py
if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
   await message.channel.send('Hello (message.author.name)!')
```

When you type the message *"$hello"* It, obviously, responds with *"Hello (message.author.name)!"* How do I get the bot to actually respond with the user's name instead. I could use:

```py
if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
   if message.author.name= myname
      await message.channel.send(myname 'Hello!')
```

But I would have to do that for each user in a server and that would take too long. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.author.name` isn't supposed to be in quotations. So you can do:

```
if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
   await message.channel.send('Hello ' + message.author.name + '!')
```

or

```
if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
   await message.channel.send(f'Hello {message.author.name}!')
```